# Magnet vertices together

Tags: mesh, modifiers, rigging

I am looking for a way to have vertices snap onto each other based on proximity and distance. For example, if I had 2 loops of vertices, I would want it to snap each vertex in loop 1 to the closest corresponding vertex in loop 2 at their midpoint. However, if they are more than a certain distance apart, the vertices would not be affected.

It would be like having 2 different loops/meshes shrinkwrap onto each other, but meeting in the middle.

I am sure this is possible with a script. Is there any way to do it without scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you could just use Remove Doubles, and adjust your merge distance.
The only thing here is they don't meet half way. That may be dependent on Mesh origin though. I'll do a little checking and get back.

> Nope this is not based on origin, I think it is more based on vertex indices based on how it acts.

[image: Remove Doubles Gif Animation]

---

Shrinkwrap with a pass of limited disolve seems to work pretty good just be sure to use it on a closed mesh that has enough topology do bend at the right places.

[image: Shrinkwrap With Limited Disolve]

Comment: That would sort of work, but then it merges the vertices. I want to keep them separate, as the mesh will be deforming.

Comment: You can always use a shrinkwrap modifier on a broken mesh like this, just be sure to check the option to keep it above the surface, and make sure it has enough subdivisions.

Comment: I appended my answer to show you what I'm talking about.